# What is the equivalent of dispatchTouchEvent for a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, touch, scrollview

I'm trying to get horizontal swipe's from a vertical `scrollview` before they are consumed by the `scrollview` in order to override them.  It can be done in an activity starting with the `dispatchTouchEvent`.

I'm trying to do the same thing in a `ListFragment` and a `Fragment`,  but `dispatchTouchEvent` doesn't seem to exist for fragments.  Is there a equivalent method to `dispatchTouchEvent` in a fragment?

Comment: no, there is no such thing

Comment: You should use a custom view, catch the touch and propigate the result manually. You can use an interface between your view and the fragment to and then delegate the action wherever you want from there. Just make a class extending scrollview and listview - catch in the scroll view and pass to the list view.

Comment: I have a custom view/adapter all within my fragment. I can't seem to override the scrollview touchevents or catch them, the typical ontouchevent and ontouch are sent back from the view hierarchy being traversed. I believe when i look at the touchevents in the fragment it's being returned from the second half of the view transversal, from the bottom up and the scollview is consuming the event. Dispatchtouchevent catches events in the first half of the view tranversal. So, are you suggesting to catch the event in the parent activity?                I was trying to keep everything in the fragment

Comment: I had issues extenting a scollview or listview in a fragment, do you have a sample that work in a fragment?  Many thanks.

Comment: i found right answer here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573026/dispatchtouchevent-in-fragment-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put the following in my parent activity in the onCreate ..., then used a public interface like Rarw mentioned above.

```
        gesturedetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener());


    myLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                bTouch = true;
                return false;
            } else {
                gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                bTouch = false;
                return true;
            }
        }

    });
```

And added the following to my parent activity and a gesturedetector to catch the desired events.

```
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);

    return gesturedetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

}
```