# How to override dispatchTouchEvent in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin

I want to use `dispatchTouchEvent` in one of many `Fragments` created in `Activity`. Problem is that `dispatchTouchEvent` causing some issues with focusing in other fragments, so I want to have it active only in single fragment, but `Fragment` doesnt have this type of function.

Is there any way how to implement it in Fragment?

I need this function, because I had issues with `EditTexts` and they refused to loose focus if I made `onClickListener` for my fragment root view (keyboard was still visible and `EditTexts` were still focused). Thats being said, I found "magic" functionality on stackOverflow which will fix those focus issues anywhere in my app:

"Magic function":

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val v = currentFocus
        if (v is EditText) {
            val outRect = Rect()
            v.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
            if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                v.clearFocus()
                val imm = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
                    imm!!.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0)
            }
        }
    }
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
}
```

I've tried to make some interceptor `View` (for example `FrameLayout`) which acts as touch detector. Then I've added `onTouchListener` and used similar code as `dispatchTouchEvent` function has. But this doesnt work. I've also tried to apply onTouchListener to my fragment `rootView` but same result.

Example (in this case interceptor is `FrameLayout` over my whole layout):

```
interceptor.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->

    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        val view = activity?.currentFocus
        if (view is EditText) {

            val outRect = Rect()
            view.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
            if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                view.clearFocus()
                val imm = view.context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager?
                imm!!.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0)
            }
        }
    }
    false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573026/dispatchtouchevent-in-fragment-in-android

Comment: Accepted answer doesnt work.

Comment: Could you point to the question you got the "magic" function from, for context?

Comment: You can't override dispatchTouchEvent in fragment. You should use it in your activity.

Comment: Check this one for hint : https://stackoverflow.com/a/52629439/1318946